# PHP Curl request running twice

Tags: php, curl, sms-gateway

Don't understand what is wrong. The code is a snippet directly from the service provider, but it still seems to run twice.

```
// Define recipients
$recipients = ['##########'];

$url = "https://gatewayapi.com/rest/mtsms";
$api_token = "******";
$json = [
    'sender' => 'Sende name',
    'message' => 'message here',
    'recipients' => [],
];
foreach ($recipients as $msisdn) {
    $json['recipients'][] = ['msisdn' => $msisdn];
}
// time: 1587715200
print_r($json);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_token.":");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($json));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print($result);
$json = json_decode($result);
print_r($json->ids);
```

Comment: Is this in a function, loop, or included/required script?

Comment: This is the entire file, only run once

Comment: Ended up quick-fixing the issue by giving the message a unique ID written into a txt file at the end of the script and checked in the beginning to see if it's already run once.